# "Which" clause with a comma

Tags: commas, which

I'm describing Step 3. Does using a comma affect what "which" modifies. Should I use a comma?

When there is a comma, does "which" refer to the entire bold clause

> **The harvested canes are then crushed in a mill**, which extracts the juice.

When there is no comma, does "which" refer to the mill?

> The harvested canes are then crushed in **a mill** which extracts the
> juice.

[image]

Comment: I would say that, with the comma, _which_ modifies _[being] crushed in a mill_.

Comment: @KateBunting, thank you. I was right about "which" modifying the mill when there is no comma?

Comment: Yes -  if it wasn't correct I would have said so. In this case, of course, it doesn't much alter the meaning of the sentence.